# Can't Delete Class Pointer

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
Class Example
{
    // ...
};

int main()
{
    Example** pointer = new Example*[9];

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        pointer[i] = new Example();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        delete pointer[i];
    }

    delete[] pointer; // <--- This is problem
    pointer = nullptr;
}
```

I'm trying to hold object's adresses in arrays. When I'm trying to delete them, for loop working great but `delete[] pointer` causes "wrote to memory end of heap buffer" error. What am I doing wrong? Should'nt  I delete that too?[image]

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Please give the full error message

Comment: `pointer[9]` is accessing the array out of bounds. Either increase the array size by one, or change the loop conditions.

Comment: @NathanOliver How can the OP improve their code example in your view?

Comment: @Kaepxer Double check your for loops. You are doing `delete pointer[i]` on a pointer outside of what you allocated with `new Example* [9]`.

Comment: `Example** pointer = new Example*[9];` - code like that shouldn't exist. There are so many better ways.. If I see stuff like that in a code review, it's a huge red flag.

Comment: I was tried that before, I was got same error. Now I tried that again and didn't get any error. Well, I'm so inattentive. Thank you all. @JesperJuhl It's just a simple example for my problem.

Comment: @Kaepxer The point is that you should not be using pointers here, if you don't have a good reason for it (unlikely). Use `std::vector<Example>` instead.

Comment: @uneven_mark I didn't mentioned in my post, sorry. It's about my homework, I have to that. Thanks for advice.

Comment: @Kaepxer I see that there is nothing you can do about it, but it is really frustrating always hearing that C++ is taught starting with pointers and `new` instead of references and standard library containers. It is completely inefficient, much more difficult and teaches bad programming practices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your array is too small:

```
Example** pointer = new Example*[9];
```

You are allocating for 9 elements, meaning their indices are 0,1,2,...,8.

In the loops here:

```
 pointer[i] = new Example();
```

and here:

```
 delete pointer[i];
```

you are accessing `pointer[9]` because your loop condition is `i < 10`. This is out-of-bounds and accessing the value causes undefined behavior.

Instead create an array with 10 elements:

```
Example** pointer = new Example*[10];
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code has undefined behavior.

You are allocating space for 9 pointers in the line

```
  Example** pointer = new Example*[9];
```

but are accessing 10 pointers in the loops following it.

Change that line to allocate 10 pointers to fix the problem.

```
  Example** pointer = new Example*[10];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your array is of 9 elements.
Your allocation loop (new) and dealocation (free) attempts to create/destroy 10 elements!

you are overflowing your array and corrupting the heap!